# Automated Testing in MVC5

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, mocking, tdd, mstest

I'm starting a new application and would like to have automated testing on most of the functionality that I want to implement. So I've been reading about TDD and how you're supposed to write test first where it should fail first (of course) then write the code to get it to pass.

1. Now, I've also read that it is recommended to use mocking framework to avoid running your tests against a database. Why is that though? Is this acceptable if I run my tests against a test database?
2. Also - is it OK to write tests on the controller level that calls the methods from the business layer or should I keep the coverage of my unit tests focused on one method? But what if the method is calling another method?
3. Does testable code means I have to do dependency injection and call methods against an interface and accept parameters as interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, I've also read that it is recommended to use mocking framework to avoid running your tests against a database. Why is that though? Is this acceptable if I run my tests against a test database?

The whole point of writing unit tests, or TDD in your case, is that you want to concentrate on writing the least amount of code to pass a test. If your class depends on another class or database, that class and database do not exist. Therefore, you write enough code to pass the test and mock everything else. Consider this requirement: "Given a string, take all the `x` characters from the string and then save the result into a datatabase". First thing you would do is write a Test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Extract_WhenCalledWithEmptyString_ShouldReturnEmpty()
{
    var extr = new XExtractor();
    var extracted = extr.Extract(string.Empty);
    Assert.IsTrue(extracted == string.Empty);
}
```

Run your test and compilation will fail because `XExtractor` does not exist. So we need to pass it. We go ahead and write the class.

```
public class XExtractor
{
    public string Extract(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Run the test and it will hopefully pass. Then your next test. Then you finally write a test that if all is well and character `x`(s) are found, the `XExtractor` must call your data access layer class at least once for the specific string. So to pass the test you write the minimum amount of code for your data access layer class to pass your test which means a simple interface with one method. Then you mock this interface and run your test and do the assertion on the mock to ensure it was called once and it was passed the string you expect to be passed to it. This whole time you are concentrating on testing the code in `XExtractor` and making sure it is calling the other dependency. What happens in that dependency, you do not care at this point. Here is what helps: Pretend you will not be writing the data access layer but someone else will write it, for example, I will be writing it all the way in Canada. I will make sure that whatever string you pass me, I will call some stored procedure and pass the string to it. I will do the database connections etc and I will return a result based on some contract (interface) you and I have agreed to. Some other person will write the stored procedure. Yet once we are all done, someone will take your class, my class, and the stored procedure and plug them into each other and it should just work. This happens at the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

After you are done with testing `XExtractor`, you start writing code for your data access layer class. But now you need to concentrate on this class and pretend you never wrote the `XExtractor` class. So all you have is the public interface of that class. So you need to write all the tests for the data access layer now, but this class needs the database. There is no database, so you write an interface and then mock the interface.

Now you know both your classes work. You move on to your database where you may need to a write a stored procedure. You write unit test to pass the sp as well. Then you replace all the mocks with real implementations and connect all the objects with real objects.

> Also - is it OK to write tests on the controller level that calls the methods from the business layer or should I keep the coverage of my unit tests focused on one method? But what if the method is calling another method?

Sure you need to do that. That is what mocks are for. In the example above when you are writing `XExtractor`, if it must call the data access layer then you will mock the data access layer. And then run assertions against it to make sure the interaction occurred.

> Does testable code means I have to do dependency injection

Yes and no. Yes, because after you are done with all the mocking then you can just ask the DI container to inject all the real dependencies into each other. You can even have a config will: one for your test dependencies and one for real dependencies. Write the config once and let the container do all the plumbing for you. But if you are just starting, then do them without dependency injection. Once you go through the pain of plugging things and doing the plumbing, then move to a dependency injection container because then you will see its real value.

> and call methods against an interface and accept parameters as interface?

You will notice that interfaces will make your job a lot easier. A lot of testing frameworks can easily mock interfaces which is really good. To mock classes, you need to have the methods virtual or some mocking frameworks will not be able to mock them. But just because you use interfaces does not mean your classes cannot use inheritance and abstraction. You can still do that but just make sure they implement the interface required.

---

**A few more points**

After a few months, you may get a different requirement because another customer wants to extract all `y` characters but they do not want to pay for the `x` extractor (imagine this is very complex). In that case you write another extractor, and I and the other developer who wrote the sp should not worry because we were just taking a string from you and saving it. Thus you write your class, you run your tests and then the person who is in charge of plugging them together will sell it to another customer. But this customer will get `YExtractor`. You get the point...

Lastly make sure you understand the difference between a mock and a stub. In the example above when testing `XExtractor`, you need to mock data access layer class. Why is it a mock? Because if your class does not call data access layer class, the test will fail. If something can make your test fail, it is a mock. Otherwise, it is a stub and it is just there to support your test.